# Is there a drum module that doesn't have sound banks, just sends the MIDI signal out through USB or Bluetooth?

Tags: midi, electronic-drumset, midi-controller-drums

I bought a used [Roland TD-4KP](https://www.roland.com/global/products/v-drums_portable_td-4kp/) with added mesh pads and cymbals.
The things is that the TD4 module that comes with it doesn't have the aux input for a 3rd cymbal, and some pads, like the toms, have a single trigger.
Is there some device that just takes the trigger input from stereo audio jacks, and sends the MIDI notes through USB or bluetooth and that's it? No sound banks, no nothing.

**Clarification:**
I *only* need one specific function of electronic drums, which is turning my trigger hits into midi notes to output to my PC and use VSTs.
The problem with most drum modules is that they don't have enough trigger inputs for the pads and cymbals I want to use, and the ones that do are usually high-end and thus very expensive.
I'm wondering if there is such a thing.

Comment: Why don't you want sound banks?  If you don't want sound coming from the module, just don't plug a speaker in.

Comment: Are you looking for a drum trigger module? But even those typically include some sounds. Specific recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Voting to leave open; to my mind this is not a "what is the best X" question but a "how do I Y" question.

Comment: Thanks, it's not that I don't want sound banks, but rather that I'm not going to use them, because I want to use VSTs only, and not pay for a full fledged drum module where I only want a part of it.

Comment: I have the feeling that a module like that would be at least as expensive as one with sound banks just because it would fit a very small market niche. Even if it was cheaper to produce, sharing the fixed costs over smaller market would make it cost more.

Comment: The round 5-pin connector on the side of the device "15" in the manual, page 7. Will send the triggers. One would need a midi to usb cable/adapter or a computer audio interface with a midi in.

Comment: Thanks, @Yorik, the problem with this set is that it has too little trigger inputs, and even some of them are mono, namely the toms, which don't have a rim trigger.
I need more trigger inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few available on the market.
Ddrum DDTi,
Alesis Trigger IO,
Roland TMC-6.

No sounds, just a midi interface. The Ddrum and Alesis are pretty much the same interface, Midi out as well as USB/Midi for triggering samples in your DAW.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to expand your kit with an additionnal module or replace your module with one with more inputs.

For extend your kit, there is eDrumIn but out of stock until 2024 right now or one of references listed in the answer of Christopher Williams.

For replacing your module with a one with more input, there is MegaDrum where you can have 32 stereo inputs for a decent price but can be hard to configure.

Comment: Yeah, for replacing the current module. I just want my e-drums go directly into this box and the proper midi signal is output to the PC, and to have as many inputs as possible.